# Unix shell - Load functions visible from sub script

Tags: function, shell, unix, subscript

I've developed a functions folder and i'm loading it in a script.

```
. /volume1/homes/David/functions/*
```

Then in the same script I use a sub script in a find command, and I would like to make functions visible in the sub script :

```
find ${source_path} -type f -name "*.${ext}" -exec sh -c '
code ...
'  {} ${dest_path} \;
```

How do you proceed ?

Thanks.

David

Answer (score 0):

You can export functions in bash with `export -f`, so they are visible in child shells.

If you don't want to add explicit export statement after each function, you can list all defined function with something like `declare -F` and export them all together from a "finisher" script.

Comment: Why do i have this message ?
bash-4.3$ export -f /volume1/homes/David/functions/log_write
bash: export: /volume1/homes/David/functions/log_write: not a function
Here is the code of my function :
log_write() {
blabla
return 0}

Comment: you need `export -f` each function name individually